# Display resized image as a return value and not as page content

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, content-type, system.drawing

On `Page_Load`, I want the page to display an image the same way it displays when you *"Open image in a new tab"*. In other words, I want the page to display as content type `Image/jpeg` instead of rendering the image in `img` HTML tag.

I successfully displayed an image this way using the below code on `Page_Load`:

```
Page.Response.ContentType="image/jpeg"
Page.Response.WriteFile("Path_to_the_Image")
```

However, my case requires displaying the image after being resized. I created a function that resizes the image and returns the resized image as `Drawing.Bitmap`

```
ResizeImage(bmSource As Drawing.Bitmap, TargetWidth As Int32, TargetHeight As Int32)
```

How can I use the returned value of that function and display it the same way I displayed the first image?

`Page.Response.WriteFile()` requires a `String` as an input. Is there a way where I can display the image of type `Image` or `System.Bitmap` directly into the page without having to save it in a temp folder and then use its path (As a `String`) and pass it to `Page.Response.WriteFile`?

Comment: This sounds like it should be a handler (ashx) instead of a page (aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Page.Response.ContentType="image/jpeg"
Using resizedImage As Bitmap = ResizeImage(source, 100, 100)
    source.Dispose()    
    resizedImage.Save(Page.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
End Using
Page.Response.Flush()
```

That should work, maybe there's some error in my syntax. I do not often code in vb.net so.

**Edited** the code because of @Joel Coehoorn note

Comment: This will work, but it will briefly hold (at least) three separate copies of the bitmap in memory (the `BitMap` object, the `MemoryStream` buffer, and the `byte[]` are all separate memory). If the image is large enough for the large object heap, that's even worse... it could be a real performance killer. Try using`Page.Response.OutputStream` directly with the  `BitMap.Save()` method.

Comment: @Rami Zebian like Joel Coehoorn said it can cause performance problens don't forget to dispose the images. Edited the above code..